# Is there a way to lock down displayName in Firebase User?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to work around the lack of a username property in firebase auth, and was thinking of storing a username in the user profile itself in the `UserInfo.displayName` property.  This is necessary so that I can get the displayname as `auth.token.name` in the security rules and then use it as a username.

However, it seems like the updateProfile method isn't locked down so it is conceivable that the user can hack the api with their token and call updateProfile directly to change that display name to someone else's username.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile

Is there a way that I can lock down that displayName so that it's not editable after by the client or after registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to limit the user profile changes to initial user registration. The public properties in that profile (currently `displayName` and `photoURL`) are the user's to change.

If you want more control over the properties kept for a user, you will have to keep them in a secondary system, such as the database that Alex mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer and as user482594 pointed out in his comment, there is no way you can "lock" `FirebaseUser` properties such as `displayName`. However, you can add that data into the database and lock it using Firebase Security Rules, as explained below.

Yes there is a way in which you can achieve this using `Firebase Security Rules`. You can do this not only for the username but for all the fields that you need. Please see the folowing line of code that you need to add in your security rules at the coresponding level.

```
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```

This means that `you can write as long as old data or new data does not exist`. In other words, if data already exists, you cannot write.

Comment: but doesn't the username exist in the Membership userinfo and not in the firebase database?  I can't set firebase rules on the Firebase.User datastore can I?

Comment: The username property exists in the Membership userinfo but in order to secure your database using Firebase rules you need create the user in your Firebase database using those properties (displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoURL, providerId and uid) and then use the desired security rules. You cannot use security rules directly on Firebase.User.

Comment: OP asked how to lock down FirebaseUser profile record. Your response seems to talk about locking down Firebase DB record, which is irrelevant. There is no security rules available for Firebase auth as of 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the username in a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). Users will not be able to modify it.

Set it on the server (or serverless function, typically triggered after a  user document creation in Firestore):

```js
getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { username: "MonkeyBonkey" })
```

Get it on the client:

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then(idTokenResult => console.log(idTokenResult.claims.username))
```